# I have a list of tuples, how can I take out a specific element?

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, tuples

I have a list of tuples like:

```
>>>list
[('the', 248),
 ('I', 81),
 ...
 ('I', 81)]
```

I want to take out a specific element like ('to',248), how should I index the element and get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> l =[('the', 248), ('I', 81), ('I', 81)]
>>> x = [i[1] for i in l]
>>> x
[248, 81, 81]
```

Comment: I am not sure what do you want as result.I hope you want to get this type of output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by this question, but if you want to take an element out with specific qualities, you would just use index() (no matter the data type):

```
# x = [("string0",0),("string1",1),("string2",2),("string3",3)]
# Example outputs:
>>> x.index(("string0",0))
0
>>> x.index(("string2",2))
2
```